# What does “the fetuses sang Az Yashir” midrash teach us

Tags: agada-stories-legends

The Gemara in Sotah brings an opinion by Rabbi Meir that even unborn fetuses in the womb sang Az Yashir. What is the deeper explanation of this midrash? Artscroll in a note lists a bunch of commentaries that have explanations on this (unfortunately they don’t bring said explanations) so what exactly are these approaches that they take, such as the maharal? What’s the midrash really teaching us?